# Multiple IP addresses in the same computer

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

I'm trying to test a comunication between two machines via ethernet. One software sends data to an IP address and another reads. Is there a way that I can have these two address in the same machine? So I can make all the testing in my computer. i.e. Software #1 sends data to 192.168.1.101 and software #2 reads this data from 192.168.1.100, everything in the same computer.

Thanks!

Comment: That's what loopback addresses are for. Send it to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Really? So I can send it to that address and read from it? I had no idea! I'm gonna try!

Comment: Any address in the range of `127.0.0.0/8` will loop back into your host. That range was set aside many, many years ago, just for this sort of thing.

Comment: I was thinking about different ports. Maybe this can be used to additional testing.